# Kivy label text starts updating too late

Tags: python, kivy

What I want is the label text showing how many times the button has been pressed, but for some reason it only starts working after I hit 2, I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't update on the first button press.

This is my python file:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock

class Testime(Widget):
    pass

class loendtest(App):
    tulemus = NumericProperty()
    loend = [0]
    def update(self, *args):
        self.loend = self.loend

    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 0.2)
        return Testime()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loendtest().run()
```

And this is the kv:

```
<Testime>:
    GridLayout:
        cols:2
        size: root.size
        Button:
            text: "lisa tulemus"
            on_press:
                app.tulemus += 1
                app.loend.append(app.tulemus)
                print(app.tulemus)
                print(app.loend)


        Label:
            text: str(app.loend[app.tulemus-1]+1) if len(app.loend) > 1 else "0"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of your code that does what you want. I have added the `kv` as a `Builder.load_string()` for my own convenience. Other stuff can be added to the code, but below is all that is needed to meet your requirements:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

class Testime(Widget):
    pass

Builder.load_string('''
<Testime>:
    GridLayout:
        cols:2
        size: root.size
        Button:
            text: "lisa tulemus"
            on_press:
                app.tulemus += 1
        Label:
            text: str(app.tulemus)
''')

class loendtest(App):
    tulemus = NumericProperty(0)

    def build(self):
        return Testime()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loendtest().run()
```